# My code doesn't work - tizen.power.request("SCREEN", "SCREEN_NORMAL");

Tags: screen, display, tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm making TIZEN Gear application on TIZEN Studio.
It needs turn on it's screen when background function catch new alarm.
there's tizen.power.request("SCREEN", "SCREEN_NORMAL"); on official site and any other users said but it's not working on my code.

I have those privileges like below

- http://tizen.org/privilege/power
- http://tizen.org/privilege/internet
- http://tizen.org/privilege/notification

and a setting values

```
background-support="enable" encryption="disable" hwkey-event="enable"


tizen.power.request("SCREEN", "SCREEN_NORMAL");
```

any error message throwing me.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if your code catches alarm event properly. I think your application is not catching the event and thus, has never called tizen.power.request().

You are missing the privilege for Alarm APIs:

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://tizen.org/privilege/alarm"/>
```

Reference: https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/web-application/alarm